# Error Using SQL Server ODBC on Mac: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Tags: python, sql-server, macos, odbc, pypyodbc

Getting this error after doing the install steps as listed out here:

```
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING=1 ACCEPT_EULA=y brew install --no-sandbox msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

Then i run python code trying to use it:

```
Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the driver code to directly reference the dylib file location instead of `{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}`:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib;SERVER='+server+';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Comment: Sure wish that microsoft would have added this info to their instructions that gave the brew formula!  I also had to change the ownership of the /usr/local/Homebrew path before the brew instructions would work under Mojave.  Thanks Micah!