# ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server: Login timeout expired [macOS]

Tags: sql-server, macos, openssl, odbc

I have this setup:

- macOS: BigSur 11.6
- SQLServer
- openssl version: OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
- `cat /etc/odbcinst.ini`, as `cat /etc/odbc.ini`, as `cat /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini`, as `/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini` - all return this:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
UsageCount=20
Trace=yes
TraceFile=/Users/sgalich/fuckingodbclogfile.log
Database=growth
Server=<my_server>
UserName=<my_username>
Password=<my_password>
Port=1433
```

- `odbcinst -j` returns this:

```
unixODBC 2.3.9
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/sgalich/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

- `cat ~/.bash_profile` returns this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export CPATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin:$PATH"
```

- and also it worth to mention that jdbc driver works perfectly with these exact server, port, username and password. Also this odbc driver was working for me a week ago with the same connection string until I restarted my laptop.

I reinstalled multiple times the ODBC Driver with this [official Microsoft instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15), reinstalled brew and openssl. Also I made symlinks, edited `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` with `source ~/.bash_profile`, I also exported all of these variables manually, changed `openssl@1.1` to `openssl@3` and just `openssl`. All of that didn't help.

I tried all of the suggested solutions from these questions:

- [Error connecting to MS SQL Server using pyODBC, unixODBC and FreeTDS (on a Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933369/error-connecting-to-ms-sql-server-using-pyodbc-unixodbc-and-freetds-on-a-mac)
- [Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'? Sym linking issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527452/cant-open-lib-odbc-driver-13-for-sql-server-sym-linking-issue)
- [Openssl still pointing to LibreSSL 2.8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62195898/openssl-still-pointing-to-libressl-2-8-3)
- [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670295/homebrew-refusing-to-link-openssl)
- https://github.com/microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release/issues/51
- https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/817
- https://github.com/microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release/issues/51
- [Error Using SQL Server ODBC on Mac: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462068/error-using-sql-server-odbc-on-mac-unixodbcdriver-managercant-open-lib-od)
- [ODBC Sql Server 17 driver on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60271649/odbc-sql-server-17-driver-on-mac-os-x)
- [dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006602/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-openssl-lib-libssl-1-0-0-dylib)
  and other

I'm still failing to connect the SQL Server and facing this error while running `isql -v -k "DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=<my_server>,1433;UID=<my_username>;PWD=<my_password>"` command:

```
[S1T00][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
[08001][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9
[08001][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
```

Please, help me solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.: Everything began with [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69457309/odbc-driver-17-for-sql-server-client-unable-to-establish-connection-macos-dja) and as turned out it was an openssl issue. May be I still didn't setup the openssl library correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't connect the VPN. Shame on me.